# Isotope Issue: Layers stuck when resizing (responsive)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to combine the responsive SKELETON framework with Isotope, but so far I am running into a problem: some of the columns stay stuck, when I resize the browser (especially if I minimize, then maximize the browser). It works if I set the webkit-animation to 0.1s or less, but so far doesn´t react correctly when I use 0.8s.

here´s what I have so far:
http://www.paulbauer.net/development/animate.html

can anyone help?

best regards,
paul

Answer (score 4):

Try giving the container a max-width and a min-width for each media query.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

    #isotainer
    {
        max-width: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        min-width: 300px;
    }       
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    #isotainer
    {
        width: 768px;
        max-width: 768px;
        min-width: 768px;
    }

}
```