# Isotope Issue: Layers stuck when change device orientation (iPad iPhone)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using responsive SKELETON framework with Isotope but when I view the page on the ipad and changing the device orientation the isotope stuck and overlay on each other until i refresh or filter it .

I tried this

[Isotope Issue: Layers stuck when resizing (responsive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979185/isotope-issue-layers-stuck-when-resizing-responsive)

But it doesn't help.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm having the same problem :/